# JSON parsing using NSURL with authorization

Tags: objective-c, json, nsurlsession, nsurl, nsurlrequest

In the following code JSONparsing method is working fine , but when I am changing url in odataJsonParsing method with:     http://192.168.1.37:8000/sap/opu/odata/sap/ZGW_BANK_DATA_SRV/BankSet?          $filter=(BankCtry%20eq%20%27IN%27)&$format=json  unable to load the data,    it is showing Nil, but same method is working fine for remaining urls,   can any one suggest me where I went wrong.

```
 **Condition**: In odataJsonParsing method have authorization credentials like.


 NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL: [NSURL           URLWithString:@"http://192.168.1.37:8000/sap/opu/odata/sap/ZGW_BANK_DATA_  SRV/BankSet?$filter=(BankCtry%20eq%20%27US%27)&$format=json"]]; 
    [request setHTTPMethod: @"GET"  ];
    // [request setHTTPBody:self.requestData];
     [request setValue:@"XXXXXXX" forHTTPHeaderField:@"username"];
     [request setValue:@"XXXXXXX" forHTTPHeaderField:@"password"];
     [request setValue:[[NSUserDefaults             standardUserDefaults]valueForKey:@"Auth"]     forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];
        [request setValue:@"application/json"   forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"]; 
    -----------------------------------------------------------------
   -(void )JSONParsing
  {
    NSError *error;
    //--------------------------URLS----------------------------//
   //http://api.geonames.org/citiesJSON? north=44.1&south=-9.9&east=-22.4&west=55.2&lang=de&username=demo

   //http://api.kivaws.org/v1/loans/search.json?status=fundraising

      //http://192.168.1.37:8000/sap/opu/odata/sap/ZGW_BANK_DATA_SRV/BankSet?  $filter=(BankCtry%20eq%20%27IN%27)&$format=json

   //http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts

   NSURL *url=[NSURL      URLWithString:@"http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts"];

   NSData  *jsonData=[[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];

   if(jsonData!=nil){
       NSDictionary *jsonArray=[NSJSONSerialization      JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers    error:&error];
      NSLog(@"%@",jsonArray);
    }

    } 

    -(void)oDataJsonParsing
   {
     NSError *error;
   NSData *jsonData=[[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL     URLWithString:@"http://192.168.1.37:8000/sap/opu/odata/sap/ZGW_BANK_DATA_    SRV/BankSet?$filter=(BankCtry%20eq%20%27IN%27)&$format=json"]];

   NSDictionary *dic=[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData   options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];
   NSLog(@"%@",dic);
   }
```

Comment: What do you want to say?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://192.168.1.37:8000/sap/opu/odata/sap/ZGW_BANK_DATA_SRV/BankSet?$filter=(BankCtry%20eq%20%27CH%27)&$format=json"];
 NSMutableURLRequest *request= [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:120.0];

NSString *authStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@:%@", @"abaper", @"initial@xyz"];
NSData *authData = [authStr dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSString *authValue = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Basic %@", [authData base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0]];

[request setValue:authValue forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];
NSError *error ;
NSHTTPURLResponse *responseCode = nil;

NSData *oResponseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&responseCode error:&error];
if([responseCode statusCode] != 200)
{

    NSLog(@"Error getting %@, HTTP status code %li", url, (long)[responseCode statusCode]);

}
else{
    NSDictionary *responsedata = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:oResponseData options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&error];

    NSLog(@"%@",response data);

   }
```